# AFJSONRequestOperation: Neither Success nor Failure Block gets called

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I have been using AFJSONRequestOperation for my iOS app, and never encountered a problem with it during my app development. However my app recently went live on the App Store and a few users started complaining about a issue, which I could track down was happening because neither success nor failure blocks of AFJSONRequestOperation were being called, and that occurs in case of a request time out.

I spent hours searching on how this can be fixed, but couldn't find an exhaustive solution. There is a long discussion on the same issue at "[Success and Failure blocks sometime not called](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/307)", but there is no conclusive word.

It's such a random issue, that it's extremely hard to reproduce. There are no crash reports associated with it, because the app wouldn't crash, but just fail to process the JSON request.

If anyone has faced a similar issue, what's the solution for it? Or at least some work around?

Comment: Are you using the newest version of AFNetworking?

Comment: It's not the latest version. We started with the app in July'13 and since it worked fine we didn't upgrade to a newer one. But if that might solve the issue, we can consider that.

Comment: Are you using Crittercism or another crash handling / analytics library?  Crittercism swizzles NSURLConnection (and so do some other libraries) so this may be your problem.  If you're using the vanilla foundation URL loading system, AFNetworking guarantees it will call one of the completion blocks.

Comment: I would definitely try updating; there have been many, many bug fixes in the last year.   The only other thing I can think of is if you have a `@try{}/@catch{}` block, and some type of exception is getting thrown.  This could cause the behavior you're describing.

Comment: Oh right, I am using Crashlytics.I wonder if that is causing the problem.

Comment: Another thing - run Charles to capture the network traffic data. Verify to make sure data is going out to your URLS. If not, then you know something may be swizzling behind the scenes as @AaronBrager pointed out.